# Unmarshalling using JAXB gives null in below code?

Tags: java, collections, jaxb, unmarshalling

Can't figure out why the umarshalled object is null in below code. Could you please point out what am I missing?

One more question:

Is it required to run a for loop in the `setStaffList(List<Staff> staffList)` in Staff class. I am bit confused on this point.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff id="1001">
        <firstname>YW</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff id="2001">
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

Unmarshalling code:

```
public class XmlToList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File xmlFile = new File("D:/CoreJavaPractice/XMLCode/src/staff.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        Company comp;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Company.class);
            comp = (Company) jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(xmlFile);
            System.out.println(comp + "; " + xmlFile);

            List<Staff> staffList = comp.getStaffList();
            System.out.println(staffList);

            for (Staff s : staffList) {
                System.out.println(s.getFirstname());
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

}
```

Company Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "company")
public class Company {
    List<Staff> staffList;

    public Company() {
    }

    public Company(List<Staff> staffList) {
        this.staffList = staffList;

    }

    public List<Staff> getStaffList() {
        return staffList;
    }

    public void setStaffList(List<Staff> staffList) {
        /*
         * for (Staff s : staffList) { this.staffList.add(s); }
         */
        this.staffList = staffList;
    }
}
```

Staff Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "staff")
public class Staff {

    Integer id;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String nickname;
    String salary;

    public Staff() {
    }

    public Staff(Integer id, String firstname, String lastname, String nickname, String salary) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setLasttname(String lasttname) {
        this.lastname = lasttname;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setNickname(String nickName) {
        this.nickname = nickName;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

}
```

Comment: According to class `Company`, it has one field named `staffList`, but XML has element named `staff`. Not same name, so not matching. --- *Hint:* Try to create the objects in memory what would match the XML, then marshal to XML and look at the result. Fix the code, i.e. give correct annotations, until the marshaled XML looks like your XML above. Now unmarshaling should work ok. --- *FYI:* `@XmlRootElement` has no impact on sub-elements. Only applies to ... *root elements!!* ... i.e. the one and only top-level element in the XML.

Comment: for (Staff s : staffList) { this.staffList.add(s) } - is this required at any situation? The suggested answers are working. But I remember seeing addition of each Staff element to staffList type code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to explicitly set `XmlAccessorType` and `XmlElement`, by this way your Company class will be:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "company")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Company {
    private List<Staff> staffList;

    public Company() {
    }

    public Company(List<Staff> staffList) {
        this.staffList = staffList;

    }

    public List<Staff> getStaffList() {
        return staffList;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "staff")
    public void setStaffList(List<Staff> staffList) {
        this.staffList = staffList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) on class and
@XmlElement(name="staff") on the variable is needed

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "company")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Company {

    @XmlElement(name="staff")
    List<Staff> staffList;

    public Company() {
    }

    public Company(List<Staff> staffList) {
        this.staffList = staffList;

    }

    public List<Staff> getStaffList() {
        return staffList;
    }

    public void setStaffList(List<Staff> staffList) {`enter code here`
        /*
         * for (Staff s : staffList) { this.staffList.add(s); }
         */
        this.staffList = staffList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or without the above said changes you can even rename the staffList to staff. That should work. We basically need to map the name from xml to the java variable.

Comment: The code you mentioned worked, but only changing  staffList to staff to does not as suggested on comments. For this to work we also need add @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD). If not setting this annotation then, we need to change the getter & setter method also to getStaff() and setStaff(..).

Answer (score 0):

Tag `List<Staff> staffList` with `@XmlElement("staff")` and you are set